# How to install uglify-js on Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci, uglifyjs

My build is failing on Travis CI because `uglify-js` won't install. The relevant parts of the output log are below. I am installing `nodejs` and `npm` because this is a `language: cpp` build not a `language: node_js` build (its a C++ library with bindings to other languages, including some client side Javascript that needs minification).

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs npm --force-yes --assume-yes --fix-broken
$ sudo npm install -g uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: uglify-js
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/travis/build/stencila/stencila/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab094.7
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "uglify-js"
npm ERR! cwd /home/travis/build/stencila/stencila
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: uglify-js
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/travis/build/stencila/stencila/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
The command "sudo npm install -g uglify-js" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Comment: According to http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Runtimes `nodejs` (and `npm`?) should already be installed. But when I removed the `apt-get` line above, I got `sudo: npm: command not found`.

Comment: Hi, I just tried with a simple [.travis.yml](https://github.com/cotsog/travisci_nodejs/blob/master/.travis.yml) file and it seems to work without having to install `npm` via `apt-get` beforehand. Here is my [build log](https://travis-ci.org/cotsog/travisci_nodejs/builds/64033106). (Even though the build failed, the log shows I was able to call `uglifyjs` successfully.) Can you provide your .travis.yml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further testing, you need to run `npm` without `sudo` to solve your problem. This way you don't need to call `apt-get` beforehand.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. That worked and fixed the build (although it is still running subsequent tasks as I write): https://travis-ci.org/stencila/stencila